# Cached CSS loading error

Tags: css, caching

Hey I'm working on a site that loads CSS and images that are generated server-side. Some times the images and CSS that is loaded in shows up as the incorrect template but with the correct images.

Since this template is created on the server and not on the actual page I was thinking that the web server that hosts the actual page may have a cached version of that page and may sometimes ignore the CSS and images that are generated from the main server.

In short:

- **Do webservers sometimes keep cached versions of page Styling?**
- **I there an easy way to make it get the live version always?**

Also this happens very infrequently and at random. It seems very hard to replicate. But I have seen it happen a few times.

**Any other Ideas?**

Comment: Just to clarify. I am look for a way to do this with code. Since these pages could be hosted on several different servers.

Answer (score 0):

For the first answer, yes they do but only if setup that way. There is the CDN or varnish. These system are used for website with huge loads where content must be cached locally or on other server, allowing the user to visualize the cached content and not the one generated by the webserver at the moment the user requested.

Exclude this for your case then ;)

I always use chrome or firebug on firefox to debug a website.
Press F12 while in the page you want to check and, on chrome, go to "Network" tab and pin "Disable Cache".
This is incredibly handy if you refresh your page quite often and want the content not cached.

For the question itself, I don't think I/we can help you without seeing the code. But try my suggestion with F12 before.

Answer (score 0):

There are two kinds of caches to think about. One of them is server cache. If you use server cache, then whenever CSS was modified, you need to empty the CSS cache if you have such a cache. If not, then you need to empty the cache, which might be painful.

As about browser cache, if you add a new parameter to your css file, then it will be loaded even if it was cached in the browser of a given user, therefore it is recommendable to add a parameter to your css file where you include it. This parameter should be either a version or a timestamp, or something uniquelly distinguishable from earlier versions. That value should be stored and you need to refresh (preferably) automatically whenever the CSS changes. The exact steps are up to you, since they differ greatly in different environments.